# php ajax reload webpage every 1 second constant database connection

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

i was wondering how can i reload a .php website containing a table every second with ajax?  is it fine if i use javascript, but a quick php script would do just fine, does a loop for reload method work?

I tried ajax with javascript but every time i used jquery load method it didnt load anything, and i 
see all ajax examples only deal with php websites that accept queries with get.
I just need my webpage to reload and check for changes in the database as quick as possible.
i tried the following code but nothing:

$("#newnav").load("polling.php");

Comment: If you just want to reload the page, you aren't doing ajax.  Forget ajax.  Forget jQuery.  You can even forget javascript, and just use a meta-refresh like @Fluffeh suggested.

Comment: true but isn't there something simpler than comet to use to keep persistent connections?. thank you though.

Comment: Many web servers will persist client connections by default.  It's called "Keep-Alive"; The browser is making new requests, but the connection is never closed.

Comment: how can i achieve this with php? as far as i know my connection seems pretty dead after it loads up.

Answer (score 1):

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5; URL=http://www.yourdomain.com/yoursite.php">
```

Pop that in your HTML code inside the  section. That will automagically reload the page every five seconds. Change the value to suit whatever time in seconds you want.

Comment: great, thanks. do you know of anything that allows me to push data to the client but it's simpler than comet?

Comment: No sorry, I am not up to date with all these fancy tools, only getting back into some coding (outside of SQL) after a good few years. My suggestion would have been to drop in an iframe with a reloading php script that outputs some javascript that your main page reads and causes it to refresh or update the HTML if needed - but I am utterly sure that a process like that is hideously outdated and archaic.